# Getting feedback on what I did wrong for 'even picks' python quiz

Tags: python-3.x

creating a function that goes through a list and returns numbers that are even.

This is the code that I put together myself:

```
def myfunc(*args):
    for x in args:
       if x%2 == 0:
          return x
```

I keep getting syntax error whenever I run this in the editor.

One solution for this is:

```
def myfunc(*args):
    return [x for x in args if x%2==0]
```

In the code I wrote, I go through the list of numbers so the second line should pass. The third line check for evens (this is also correct syntax). Why is it not returning?

Answer (score 1):

your return statement in `myfunc` will return the *first* element that is even. If you want to return all elements that are even, then you should use a list comprehension as you did, or modify `myfunc` to contain an array, and append all even numbers into it, like so:

```py
def myfunc(*args):
        ret_arr = []
        for x in args:
           if x%2 == 0:
               ret_arr.append(x)

        return ret_arr
```

Also, you original function code is syntactically correct, i had no issues running it on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

```
Numbers = []
for i in range(1, 101):
     if i % 2 == 0:
        Numbers.append(i)
Print(numbers)
```